# Pressure in a drop at equilibrium diverges at $r=0$

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, stress-strain

Assume a spherical drop. The force equilibrium writes, since the divergence of the stress tensor is null and the stress is isotropic:
$$
\nabla \cdot (\underline{\underline{\sigma}})=\underline{0}\Rightarrow \nabla \cdot (\underline{\underline{P}})=\underline{0} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r (r^2P)=0 \Rightarrow P \sim \frac{1}{r^2}
\,.$$

And there is a singularity at $r=0$!

How do you explain that, and how to make sense of it?

Comment: It appears you don't take into account surface tension ? This will have effects at such low radii. In any case, you cannot take your drops radius to zero without having to deal with quantum effects, so you could say that you have a cutoff for some small radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got my answer from somebody :

If the stress is isotropic, in fact, the stress writes $\sigma_{\alpha \beta}=-p \delta_{\alpha \beta}$, and $div(\underline{\underline{\sigma}})=0\Rightarrow-\partial_r p=0$ and not $-1/r^2  \partial_r(r^2 p)$, and the pressure is constant at equilibrium, and its value given by the condition on the surface $p=p_{ext}+2\gamma / R$, with $R$ the radius of the drop.